# Is wrong to use redirects in a Rest API server?

Tags: rest

Is considered a bad practice to do redirects from a Rest API server?

For example when doing OAuth2 code authorization flow.

Comment: What application are you planning to build that would use the API's exposed by REST API server. How are you planning to use Outh2 code auth granty type flow. Do you have a separate web server ? What is the REST API server build on..which technology.

Comment: @Rohan I would like the backend to start the OAuth flow using the PKCE extension, so it will need to generate a code and redirect the user (through the browser) to the auth server and after the user signs in on the auth server, the auth server would redirect the user back to the frontend with the code to exchange with the token. Then frontend would send this code to the backend and the backend using this code and the PKCE generated code would exchange it with auth tokens.

This way frontend will never know about PKCE generated code, thus there isn't a way for leakage.

Comment: Okay. so you planning to implement OAuth code grant type with PKCE. In this case, I don't think your REST server would be required to do any redirect. You REST server just hosts rest services to respond to request. An additional logic that you can put in your REST API server is to validate the JWT's sent by the front/middle tier and validate it against the keys provided by auth server. The frontend/middle tier would have to have a logic of redirecting when it finds the user is logging in for the first time or the users access token is not cached.

Comment: @Rohan. I want to manage the PKCE code in the backend. So it would be like this.

User click on login button, so it sends a log-in request to API.
API generates PKCE code and returns a redirection to OAuth server with the hashed PKCE code.
... the flows continues as normal. 
As you can see there is 1 step saved and also PKCE is never known in the frontend, so there is even more security for the tokens to no be leaked.

In any case, my question is just about if it is a bad practice or not to return a redirection in API requests. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirects are commonly used in OAuth2 to a login token back to the website. This allows the user to identify the user with an external service, and more.

#### Discord OAuth2 Flow

**/login** --> **discord.com/login...** --> **discord.com/oauth2/authorize** --> **/auth-redirect?code=<from_discord>** --> **localhost:3000/auth?token=<from_our_api>**

**Express.js Example**:

`'/auth-redirect'` would be the route that the third party (e.g. Discord login) sends the code to, after the user clicks 'Authorize' on discord.com.

```js
app.get('/auth-redirect', (req, res) => {
    // ... do something with the code received from the third party
    // ... return token that can be used to access our API (e.g. login)
    res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000?token=${apiToken}`);
});
```

In this example, we are redirecting back to the website URL, and we are now able to store the token in cookies, or localStorage by getting the token from the query params.

**Website Script**:

```js
// window.location.search -> '?token=...'
const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
localStorage.setItem('token', query.get('token'));
```

**More Info on Redirects** -
https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

Redirects can be used for other things like sending success messages.

```js
// Tell the website user, that they verified their email.
// Handle the query message on the website.
res.redirect(`${websiteURL}?message=Successfully verified your email.`)
```

### Where to not use redirects

There's also places where it does not make sense to use redirects. This assumes that the website is not built in to the API, but just sends requests to it - i.e. you are using a front-end framework.

```js
// DELETE the user, by id, from the database.
app.delete('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
    // ... delete user
    // ... redirect back to the website?
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
});
```

### Conclusion

There's a lot of use cases for redirects in APIs, especially when the website is built into the API (front-end built with back-end). Furthermore, I'd say it is good practice to use redirects in OAuth2 as routes depend on each other in a chain.

The JS code is just an example. This is how I use redirects, in an API, in one of my applications. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: "when the website is built into the API (front-end built with back-end)" - In that case you are not talking about an API.  This answer is confusing, because it is technology-specific, and mixes web and API concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's bad, as it clashes on a definition basis with REST architecture.

While you can use it that way, it's nearly the same as using `.jpg` as a mean to store audio files - yes, you can do it, but you definitely shouldn't.

---

REST is used only for web resources and thus cannot be a part of the logic of your application. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

You can, however, return the "redirection" link through the REST API. This way you won't break the convention.
Or you can create a new, smaller service just for redirection.

Comment: You said that "Yes, it's bad, as it clashes on a definition basis with REST architecture.". Could you please share with which definition basis of REST architecture the redirection pattern clashes?